# How to encrypt a value in a EXEC stored procedure?

Tags: c#, sql-server, encryption, stored-procedures

I have this as a query in Microsoft SQL Server

```
EXEC StoredProcedureName "Email", "pinNumber";
```

and in my C# code, I have a function that takes the `pinNumber` and encrypts it.

How can I encrypt `pinNumber` in my `EXEC` statement so it would match what I have in the source code?

Comment: Store the pinNumber is DataBase as encrypted way, so u wont have to do this again

Comment: Why do you need to encrypt it again? Wouldn't you be passing in the encrypted value? That is kind of the point.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174415.aspx

Comment: I need to encrypt it again because im manually entering data into the database using EXEC  to populate my database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two solutions, you can choose one of them according to your requirement.

- Dont Encrypt the pinNumber, just pass as plain text in stored
  procedure and compare it.
- If you want to encrypt this in C# code and pass in stored procedure, then better you store pinNumber value in table as
  encrypted text. It will be better solution from security point of
  view.

If you do encryption in Stored Procedure there are multiple drawbacks of this solution.

- Unnecessary encryption of pinNumber in C# code.
- Slow execution of Stored Procedure.
- Less secure(If pinNumber is a secured field)

Comment: The reason id like to encrypt it in sql is because im populating my database using exec and would like the pin number to be as if it was entered by the user and encrypted in my c# code.  @vivek nuna

Comment: im populating my database using exec? what difference it makes ?

Comment: meaning im entering it manually and its not going through my c# code, so the pin number i enter in sql doesnt go through my encrypting method.

Comment: and why do you want to encrypt it in stored procedure ?

Comment: because if i store "123456" as a pin number and try to access the website using that pin number "123456" its invalid since 123456 isnt encrypted.

Comment: which encryption algo are you using in C# code? Why are you calling stored procedure manually. You should call it from your C# code. If you want to call stored procedure manually then you can develop a small app to encrypt the pinNumber and then pass this value to stored procedure manually.